# Emacs Dired: Sorting by time / date as default

Tags: emacs, dired

In `emacs dired`-mode, when I press `s` I can toggle between alphabetical and chronological sorting of files. Usually, I always prefer chronological sorting, but alphabetical sort is the default. How can I customize emacs to always have a dired buffer first show up chronologicaly sorted?

Comment: Customize the variable `dired-listing-switches` -- it's basically the `ls` command *string* that has certain limitations based on the particular `ls` version installed, and `dired-mode` doesn't accept a `list` format (so I created my own custom version of dired that supports a list).  See also this helpful library:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired-sort.el

Comment: @lawlist points to one Emacs Wiki page that covers this topic. [**Here**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSorting) is the page that deals with the topic generally. It covers multiple libraries that help with Dired sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just repeating @lawlist comment:

> Customize the variable `dired-listing-switches`

For example: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `dired-listing-switches`
Fill the field with `-lt`

Or just setq it in your `.emacs` or `init.el` with:

`(setq dired-listing-switches "-lt")`

Comment: I wrongly thought this solution would disable the possibility to sort alphabetically, since now `-t` option would always be present.  However, this is not the case, and pressing `s` in `dired-mode` now toggles to alphabetically sorted, exactly what OP (and I) wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered this package in melpa, which makes (persistent) sorting in dired very easy: https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-quick-sort